# How to display analysis variable (0 - 1) as percentage using Proc Tabulate in SAS?

Tags: sas, proc

Suppose I have this data set like this:

[Sample Data Set](http://s749.photobucket.com/user/liverton11/media/employsample.jpg.html)

And I would like to set up a table using proc tabulate such that it will look like:

[Sample Tabulate](http://s749.photobucket.com/user/liverton11/media/sampletable.jpg.html)

So far I have codes like this:

```
    PROC TABULATE
    DATA = EMPLOY;
    CLASS RACE STATE;
    VAR EMPLOYED;
    TABLE RACE*STATE, N EMPLOYED*SUM EMPLOYED*PCTSUM<TABLE*RACE>;
    RUN;
```

But it doesn't seem to give me what I want, is there anyway to fix it?  I know it is odd using 0-1 and treat employed as an analysis variable for this but my boss doesn't want any 'N' (0) columns, just the 'Y' (1) columns.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Data=` is an option for the `Proc` statement, not a separate statement.

```
PROC TABULATE DATA = EMPLOY;
```

You correctly identify CLASS and VAR variables

```
CLASS RACE STATE;
VAR EMPLOYED;
```

and as boolean `TRUE`  is coded as `1`, you can sum it up to count the number employed, but `SUMPCT` gives you the column percent, *i.e how many employed subjects are ASIANs living in NC?*

To calculate the fraction employed per race and state, you can average the boolean:

```
TABLE RACE*STATE, N EMPLOYED*(SUM MEAN);
RUN;
```

And this gives you the required data, though ugly formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I just changed that it still doesn't give what I want.